# C# - How to write an object that requires a DB connection

Tags: c#, object

I'm new to creating objects and such in C# (winforms) and need to know the best approach to this.  I've got a simple object that will return some data from our database.  Normally, I would put the DS string (encoded) in the object and be done but the issue I've found with that is this doesn't make the object truely "mobile" to be able to be used in any of our applications (web or windows).  So, is it best to create an object that requires the encoded db string in the constructor or how should I go about doing it?

Here's what I was thinking:

```
public class foo
{
    public foo(string EncodedConnectionString)
    {
        _EncodedConnectionString = EncodedConnectionString;
    }

    private string _EncodedConnectionString { get; set; }

    private DataSet GetFooFromDB()
    {
        oDatabase = new SQLDataBase(
            EncodedConnectionString, 15);

        //remaining code omitted...
    }
}
```

Thoughts, comments?

Comment: Could you clarify a situation where an identical connection string to the same database would work in one context, but not another?

Comment: Without knowing your complete scenario... This looks fine, what issue are you having moving this object to projects?

Comment: Why create your own framework?  There are many frameworks readily available like EF, linq2SQL, nHibernate, etc.

Comment: Cpfhol - There isn't with an indentical connection string but different for applications (unless I'm not aware of something, which could be the case).  As far as I knew, the connection string for a windows app is different than an ASP.NET app, so therefore, I wouldn't be able to use a certain connection string if I wanted to use this object in both windows and web.

Comment: Jon C - I haven't implemented it this way yet, just wanted opinions on the best approach/practice.  I believe this will work though.

Comment: Maess - We already have a DAL which provides us the methods for executing SP's, etc. against our DB so I didn't want to change anything at the moment.

Comment: @Robert: the actual connection strings are the same regardless of if it's a windows app, asp.net, java, php, etc.  The only question is how to pass it in for that particular language.  In the case of a .Net windows app versus an asp.net app.. it's the exact same mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the objects themselves should be agnostic when it comes to persistence.  What I mean by that is that the objects should neither care nor even be aware of how they are being stored/loaded.

There are multiple ways to accomplish persistence.  One way is to have a DAL (Data Access Layer) which knows how to load and store the data associated with your objects.  Bear in mind though, that even the DAL won't have the connection string hard coded but rather should pull it from your config file as necessary.

A simple example is here: http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/dataaccesslayerdesign1.aspx  Personally, I don't agree with everything on how that was done, but it's a good starting point to learn about them.

For a little more advanced reading look at the Entity Framework http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx

Another way is to use Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection.  The idea being that your object would have `Save()` and `Load()` methods which accepted some type of interface that performed the actual persistence.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973811.aspx

This is a bit more complicated to get your head around but pays dividends with the flexibility to swap out repositories on demand.  Meaning that it is much simpler to support multiple database backends or even storing the objects in csv / xml files.

Comment: _"Actually, the objects themselves should be agnostic when it comes to persistence. What I mean by that is that the objects should neither care nor even be aware of how they are being stored/loaded."_

This is what I thought based on what I've read recently.  It seems to be the best approach....thank you for the links!

Answer (score 2):

What I whould change in your code is:

```
public class foo
{
    private SQLDataBase _sqlDataBase;
    public foo(SQLDataBase sqlDataBase)
    {
        _sqlDataBase = sqlDataBase;
    }
}
```

Now you are able to test your code with dependency injection. The connectionstring is externally added so you can change the database without rewiring/rewriting a lot of code.

Comment: Thank you for this as well....I like this approach as it appears to give the flexibility.